# React router: nested resources

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have a two routes:

```
/resource/1/

/resource/1/nested_resource/2
```

And appropriate `<Link />` components. 
When i go to route `/resource/1/`- only links that forward to `/resource/1/` have `active` class.

But when i go to `/resource/1/nested_resource/2` path, links for `/resource/1/` and `/resource/1/nested_resource/2` have active class.

Is there a way, in second case, to give active class only for nested route links like `/resource/1/nested_resource/2`?

```
 <Route path='/' component={Layout}>
  <IndexRoute component={Index} />
  <Route path='resource' >
    <IndexRoute component={Resources} onEnter={onEnter} />
    <Route path='new' component={NewResource} />
    <Route path=':resourceId' onEnter={onEnter}>
      <IndexRoute component={ShowResource} onEnter={onEnter} />
      <Route path='nested_resource' >
        <Route path=':nestedResourceId' component={NestedResource} />
        <Route path='new' component={NestedResourceNew} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an < IndexLink /> which will be active only when the parent route matches.

react-router [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/IndexRoutes.md) says -

> If you were to < Link to="/">Home in this app, it would always
>   be active since every URL starts with /. This is a problem because
>   we'd like to link to Home but only be active if Home is rendered.
>
> To have a link to / that is only active when the Home route is
>   rendered, use < IndexLink to="/">Home< /IndexLink>.